# select lines with n identical fields, after a sentinel character

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

In my file, each line includes five numerical fields delimited by spaces (preceded and followed by more fields). Via a shell script I need to be able to select lines with exactly 3, 4 and 5 identical entries among those five numeric fields (i.e. three separate searches, such that the search for lines with 3 matches in those fields does not also return lines with 4 or 5 matches in those fields).

<strike>To find the relevant fields, my search will have to locate the first open and closed parenthesis pair on a line. After the parenthesis is closed, the immediately following five fields are the ones I'm interested in. One potential complication: sometimes one or more of the numeric fields is replaced by a single dash/hyphen instead of a number. One potential means of simplification: the five fields will be in (non-strictly) ascending order and any hyphen entries will always precede the remaining numeric fields.</strike>

I would be grateful for some sed/awk suggestions with this. Many thanks!

[EDIT]: I can extract the relevant fields (as detailed in the comment below), thus the strike-through paragraph above is unnecessary. Here is sample data once the relevant fields are extracted:

```
109 110 111 111 112
110 110 111 111 112
99 99 99 112 112
99 99 99 112 112
100 101 101 112 112
102 102 102 112 112
102 102 103 112 112
102 103 103 112 112
102 104 104 112 112
102 104 104 112 112
103 104 104 112 112
102 105 105 112 112
102 105 105 112 112
103 105 105 112 112
102 106 106 112 112
102 106 107 112 112
103 106 107 112 112
104 106 107 112 112
102 107 107 112 112
104 107 107 112 112
104 107 107 112 112
106 107 108 112 112
107 107 108 112 112
107 107 108 112 112
102 109 109 112 112
102 109 109 112 112
104 109 109 112 112
102 109 110 112 112
103 109 110 112 112
104 109 110 112 112
102 110 110 112 112
104 110 110 112 112
104 110 110 112 112
107 109 111 112 112
107 109 111 112 112
106 110 111 112 112
107 110 111 112 112
107 110 111 112 112
109 110 112 112 112
110 110 112 112 112
107 112 112 112 112
112 112 112 112 112
```

This should produce hits when n=3 on these lines:

```
99 99 99 112 112
99 99 99 112 112
102 102 102 112 112
109 110 112 112 112
110 110 112 112 112
```

A hit when n=4 on this line:

```
107 112 112 112 112
```

and a hit when n=5 on this line:

```
112 112 112 112 112
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  To [complete your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34602978/edit), please include usable sample data, an example of the output you're looking for, the code you've written so far, and the output (or errors) your code generates. We'd be only to happy to help you with this, but *your code* is the starting point.

Comment: @ghoti is there a UI way to insert that text, or are you just pasting it in manually?

Comment: The code I've written so far just isolates the five fields: 
`cat myfile | cut -d ')' -f 2 |  sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f1-5`
I don't really know where to begin with the matching part. But I should have simplified the question so it only asked about how to find lines with n matching fields among 5 fields, as the "sentinel" thing I can solve. Thanks.

Comment: Please post sample input and expected output.

Comment: And please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34602978/edit). Comments mangle formatting in rather spectacular ways. The place for the important elements of your question is in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Bash script solution using `awk`. It reads the file line by line and uses an [AWK associative array](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/awk-arrays-explained-with-5-practical-examples/) to count how many times a number appeared on the line. Change `filename.txt` to your file that contains the numbers.

```
n=3
while read line
do
    echo "$line" | awk -v n="$n" '
        {
            for(i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
                a[$i]++
            }
        }
        {
            for(o in a) {
                if (a[o] == n) {
                    print
                }
            }
        }
        '
done < filename.txt
```

Comment: thank you, works beautifully. I can't believe how simple the syntax for accessing the members of the associative array is.

Comment: May I suggest that instead of escaping your quotes to refer to `$n`, you simply pass the variable in to awk by using the `-v` option?  `awk -v n="$n" 'this {that}'`.  Also, beware of this use of `printf`. If `$line` (which incidentally does not exist within the scope of the awk script) contains formatting characters, you will get unpredictable results, most likely errors.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks, I didn't know of that Awk feature. I updated my answer, and changed the `printf` to `print`.

Comment: Great start. Note that `$line` still does not exist within the awk script -- a line of input is stored in `$0`, but simply running `print` by itself will print the current line.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `sed` as well.
You can create a `script`:

```
n=$(($1-1))
sed -n "/\([0-9]*\)\( \1\)\{$n\}/p" filename
```

And run it like this, just supply `n` as a script argument:

```
./script.sh 3
```

Output:

```
99 99 99 112 112
99 99 99 112 112
102 102 102 112 112
109 110 112 112 112
110 110 112 112 112
```

Comment: Thank you, these compact scripts are exactly the kind of thing that makes me feel I need to learn sed thoroughly and simulatneously makes me despair of ever reaching that point, as a hobbyist who only needs to do such tasks on the order of once a year.

Comment: you are welcome, you actually don't need to learn sed, you need to understand regex, it works the same way for all languages

Answer (score 2):

Another sed example, didn't want my work to go to waste ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
while (($1 > 0))
do
    n="${n} \1"
    set ${1}-1
done
sed -nr "\_\<([0-9]+)${n}\>_ p"
```

EDIT:
On BSD `sed` (OS X) you need to replace `\<` and `\>` with the fascinating `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Awk-only solution as a one-liner:

```
awk -v n=3 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++;for(o in a)if(a[o]==n)p=1} p; {p=0;delete a}' inputfile
```

Split out for easier reading, this slightly resembles badjr's solution. (I've used his variables for easier comparison.)

```
{
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)     # populate an array with counts of unique elements
    a[$i]++
  for (o in a)            # check the array for a matching count & set flag
    if (a[o]==n)
      p=1
}

p;       # if we've set our flag, print the current line.

{        # clear our workspace for the next line.
  p=0
  delete a
}
```

If you're interested in a bash-only solution, the following implements the same awk logic, only without awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=5

while read -a a; do
  unset b
  for i in "${!a[@]}"; do
    (( b[${a[$i]}]++ ))
  done
  for i in "${b[@]}"; do
    [ "$i" -eq "$n" ] && echo "${a[@]}"
  done
done < inputfile
```

Note that because the output here is printed using array elements, whitespace in the input file will not be maintained.

This solution is bash-only because of its use of arrays.